# Would leaving a graduate scheme early look bad on my resume?

Tags: resume, career-development, recruitment, quitting, career-switch

I'm currently on a 2 year graduate scheme doing non technical work for a large engineering company.  I've recently had a change of situation which means that I may have the opportunity of working and living in a different country, I'm really interested in this opportunity but to take it I would have to leave my current job before the completion of the 2 year graduate scheme.

Will this have a negative affect on my resume?  I'm thinking I want to reskill and would be looking at jobs in a different sector to my current one, I would consider starting a different graduate scheme for a new company.

Both the country I currently live within and the country I would move too are within the European Union so visas etc, would not be an issue.

Comment: Once you gain experience in the job you want, this history will not be significant.

Comment: Yeah, I was just nervous that me dropping out half way through a supposed training period might look bad.  Though, most of the training is on the job so I doubt it's important if I want a fresh start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't have a negative effect on your CV for 3 reasons:

1. Hiring managers know that [the average length of time a graduate is in their first job is 18 months](http://tsrmatters.com/18-months-the-average-duration-of-a-graduates-first-job/)
2. You wouldn't list that you left before the end of the 2 year scheme. It doesn't add anything to your CV to do so
3. If you are successful in your application, then you have boosted your career early. That does leave a negative impression on a CV

Answer (score 1):

If you have a great offer, quit. Be honest, tell your current employee you have great opportunity and you think it will be the best option for you.
Of course It would be difficult to return to your current employer, but if you are sure that it is good for you, do it.
One  short-term job on resume is OK, even if it was meant to be fixed-time.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I would have to leave my current job before the completion of the 2 year graduate scheme. Will this have a negative affect on my resume?

I've been in similar positions on the hiring side before, and don't think that this would *necessarily* have a negative effect.

Many people have aspects of their CV that need some context to understand - periods out of work, short tenure, returning to same place etc. If you are prepared to succinctly explain why (and the reason given above sounds very reasonable) then this doesn't have to be negative at all. In some ways, a clear idea of what you want to achieve, and being prepared to make drastic changes to get there can be a positive thing.

Also worth bearing in mind that the significance of your employment history diminishes with time. If you go on to a couple of years somewhere else then an employer is likely to weight their consideration in favour of recent relevant history.

Where I believe this would have a negative effect is with the employer who brought you on to the graduate program. Should you wish to reapply there at some point in the future then they may count this against you. On the other hand, if you end up working there again, then their investment in you was not wasted.

Finally, patterns of behaviour will be interpreted much stronger than isolated events. If your CV in five years shows a string of unfinished projects, short engagements without clear reason etc then that can limit your success.